# CoreBluetooth didDiscoverPeripheral not called

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I have a singleton called BLE in order to manage everything about the ble connections.

This is my code (well, the important parts):

```
class BLE: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    static let instance = BLE()
    private var data: NSMutableData?
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        self.data = NSMutableData()
    }

    func startScanning(timeout: Double) -> Bool {
        if self.centralManager.state != .poweredOn {
            print("[ERROR] Couldn´t start scanning")
            return false
        }
        print("[DEBUG] Scanning started")
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeout, target: self, selector: #selector(BLE.scanTimeout), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])

        return true
    }

    private func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject],RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("[DEBUG] Find peripheral: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString) RSSI: \(RSSI)")
    }

}
```

I think i've read everything to read about it online, i've tried different classes but nothing seems to call the "didDiscoverPeripheral" method.

When I check my bluetooth connections on my settings app I see 3 different devices.

What could possibly go wrong? Is there a capability i'm not aware of that I should turn on? Does it not work well with singletons? I'm starting to loose my grip here...

Help, anyone...

Comment: If you are using Swift 3 or more, your method is not the same as the one in the doc. Check the one present in your documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091#40492091 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49305420/diddiscoverservices-is-not-being-called-after-a-ble-connection/49306695#49306695

Comment: Or "When I check my bluetooth connections on my settings app I see 3 different devices."; They are probably not Bluetooth Low-Energy. Are you sure the device your are looking for is Bluetooth Low Energy? Can you see it with LightBlue.app (free app and great tool to debug Bluetooth Low Energy devices)?

Comment: You are a life saver!!!! Can you please post your answer so I could accept it? Thank you so much!!! This was indeed the wrong method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working, Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3)