# Get selected value from picker view (picker wheel)

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm currently using XCode version 11.3.1 (11C505) and Swift 5 and I can't seem to find a good answer as to how to get the selected value from a picker wheel (view). Here's the relevant code from my `ViewController.swift`

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var numberPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var test: UILabel!

    private let possibleNums: [Int] = Array(1...16) // Create an array of Ints from 1 to 16
       
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        numberPicker.dataSource = self
        numberPicker.delegate = self
    }
}


extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return possibleNums.count
    }
    // Attempt at getting the selected value, didn't work
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int {
        print(possibleNums[numberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])
        test.text = "\(possibleNums[numberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])"
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(possibleNums[row])
    }
}
```

Edit: Solution was also in comments so I figured I'd put it here in case anyone else finds this:
`func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int` should be `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int` (missing `_`)
and `test.text = "\(possibleNums[numberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])"` should just be `test.text = "\test.text = "\(possibleNums[row])"`

Comment: I guess you method isn't called? That's normal: `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int` that's not the one in the doc. Remove it, and rewrite it, let autcompletion help you, or just replace it with correct one see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306695/1801544 it's the same issue.

Comment: @Larme yea, ending up missing an underscore at the start of the function arguments (should have been `_ pickerView`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `test.text = "\(possibleNums[numberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])"` to this: `test.text = "\(possibleNums[row])"`

You only have one component, so you don't need to check for it, just return the row number as the array's index.

Comment: Thanks! This and another comment definitely pointed me to the right answer (missed an underscore at the start of the function arguments)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to change your `didSelectRow` function from

```swift
test.text = "\(possibleNums[numberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])"
```

to

```swift
test.text = "\(possibleNums[rows])"
```